Restructure and add key-value pair to json string at run-time using Newtonsoft
I'm trying to deserialize the following json string to a series of custom c# classes below.   I'm not sure if this is the right or best approach but short of doing a Find/Replace on the json string(doesn't seem like a very clean way to do it, there must be a better way than that) I'm not sure what else can be done.
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "NVDA",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2024-12-06",
        "4. Output Size": "Full size",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2024-12-06": {
            "1. open": "144.6000",
            "2. high": "145.7000",
            "3. low": "141.3100",
            "4. close": "142.4400",
            "5. volume": "188505573"
        },
        "2024-12-05": {
            "1. open": "145.1100",
            "2. high": "146.5400",
            "3. low": "143.9500",
            "4. close": "145.0600",
            "5. volume": "172621180"
        },
        // Many more entries

But, I want to rearrange and reorganize the json to:
"MetaData": {
            "Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
            "Symbol": "NVDA",
            "LastRefreshed": "2024-12-06",
            "OutputSize": "Full size",
            "TimeZone": "US/Eastern"
        },
        "TimeSeries": {
            "Data": {
                "open": "144.6000",
                "high": "145.7000",
                "low": "141.3100",
                "close": "142.4400",
                "volume": "188505573", 
                "date": "2024-12-06",
                "series": "Daily"
            },
            "Data": {
                "open": "145.1100",
                "high": "146.5400",
                "low": "143.9500",
                "close": "145.0600",
                "volume": "172621180",
                "date": "2024-12-05",
                "series": "Daily"
            }
        }

So I can create the following classes
    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("open")]
        public string open { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("high")]
        public string high { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("low")]
        public string low { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("close")]
        public string close { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("volume")]
        public string volume { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public string date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("series")]
        public string series { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("MetaData")]
        public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("TimeSeries")]
        public TimeSeries TimeSeries { get; set; }
    }

    public class TimeSeries
    {
        [JsonProperty("Data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetaData
    {
        [JsonProperty("Information")]
        public string Information { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Symbol")]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Last Refreshed")]
        public string LastRefreshed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Output Size")]
        public string OutputSize { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Time Zone")]
        public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    }   

This way I could deserialize the json string.  I've done some research looking in to this but I haven't found what I'm looking for yet.  I'm using Newtonsoft and I'd like answers to use Newtonsoft as well.  But, if there is something better out there I'll be willing to switch to another package.  First, I'd like to know if this approach would work.  If not, I'd like ideas on how communiy members would tackle this problem.

The intended JSON isn't even normalized: it has duplicate Data keys in Time Series. Perhaps you should have a single Data key with an array of objects?

As noted by @Charlieface, your proposed JSON has duplicate keys.  While duplicate keys are not disallowed by JSON RFC 8259, they are discouraged: The names within an object SHOULD be unique... When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable... Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the object.  Can you please confirm you really want that?

Incidentally, your current "Time Series (Daily)" JSON property value can easily be serialized as a [JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")] public Dictionary<string, Data> { get; set; } or Dictionary<DateOnly, Data> so I recommend sticking with the current format.

If you must serialize and deserialize duplicate property names you will need to write a converter.  Does How to serialize and deserialize a JSON object with duplicate property names in a specific order? answer your question?  I'm not sure it answers your question exactly because it requires a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> property where the KeyValuePair.Key is the (possibly duplicated) property name -- but in your case the duplicated property name is always "Data".
